# How to run flutter app on specific iPhone or iPad model?

Tags: flutter

I follow this [flutter tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) for how to setup iPhone simulator for flutter.
But this tutorial pick latest version of iPhone simulator. I want to run my flutter app in different iPhone, iPad simulators.

How my flutter app run on both iPhone simulators (iPhone and iPad)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following command from the Terminal / command prompt :

```
flutter run -d all
```

Alternatively, use the device id on which you would like to run. Example below :

```
flutter run -d fesjsh293dlhdksljafdj
```

To start different simulators, click on menu > Hardware > Device > iOS 12.2 >

Note : Instead of 'iOS 12.2' you may have different iOS version on your machine.

Comment: I am using flutter run -d  3BA2543B-8A49-4257-9BE7-7F34F0596C2E

and show this message in terminal 

No devices found with name or id matching 3BA2543B-8A49-4257-9BE7-7F34F0596C2E.

3BA2543B-8A49-4257-9BE7-7F34F0596C2E this is my iPad id

Comment: This ID won't work. Just run command  `flutter run`. It'll display the connected devices along with their ID. Pick-up the ID from their and use with `-d`.

Comment: Only one Device connect with Flutter that is iPhone XR. But I want to connect iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) and run flutter app on it

Comment: What is the output of `flutter run` ?

Comment: When I run the command @flutter run the application run in iPhone XR

Comment: This means, iPad pro is not started. Flutter is taking the ONLY device available and running it. Try running `flutter devices` to list all the connected devices and please share the output.

Comment: 1 connected device:
<br/>
<br/>
iPhone Xʀ • 146CF7BB-1DDD-40AA-A737-44322DF51BD3 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4
(simulator)

Comment: So, there's only one connected device. That's the reason, the code is not running on iPad Pro. Now, in Simulator, click on menu > Hardware > Device > iOS 12.2 > iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation). Wait a bit and let the device start. And then run `flutter run -d <device id>`

Comment: Yes Now app running in iPad Pro

Answer (score 4):

step1:- Run `flutter devices`, You will get list of devices connected. like this.

```
2 connected devices:

Redmi 4                   • 81cea4a7d740  • android-arm64 • Android 7.1.2 (API
25)
Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86   • Android 9 (API 28)
(emulator),
```

step2:- f you want to run in a specific device Run `flutter run -d Device name or Device id`
eg:- `flutter run -d Redmi` or `flutter run -d 81cea4a7d740`,

step3:- If you want to run in all devices than `flutter run -d all`.